# Change to root directory as workspace in EC2 Rstudio

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, shiny, rstudio, rstudio-server

I just set up rstudio server in EC2 following this URL - https://www.r-bloggers.com/instructions-for-installing-using-r-on-amazon-ec2/

Everything looks good, however, I am trying to set up this instance in a way to develop the shiny app using this rstudio and access it through http://host-name:3838/shinyapp/ (For this, i need to place the app folder under /srv/shiny-server.

However when I try to write my code in EC2 rstudio, I logged in to http://host-name:8787/ using the rstudio user i created, but I need to access the /srv folder under root.

1. Is it possible to login to rstudio server using root?
2. Else is it possible to access the root directory from rstudio server (logged in with rstudio user)?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not navigate to `/srv` from the file navigator in the bottom right pane of rstudio? If not, it's probably because of permission issues. I'm not a great sysadmin so I won't give any advice there... but I say that you can follow my (disclaimer: I wrote it) tutorial for setting up rstudio on a cloud server (using digitalocean instead, but steps are almost identical). It takes care of permissions and a lot of other small steps that are usually left out http://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean

Comment: No I could not navigate beyond home folder on it. Also I can only see rstudio user folder under home in bottom right pane of rstudio.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I think the problem is rstudio server does not allow root to login as a user. If you look at the documentation link below, it looks like you should be able to set `auth-minimum-user-id=100` in rserver.conf. I have not been able to get this to work in the community edition though.
http://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/authenticating-users.html#restricting-access-to-specific-users

Comment: Thanks for commenting on this. I was never able to solve this. I am also using community edition, so i may not able to solve, however i will give it a try. Thanks again. :)